# is there a way to make animated arc in flutter?

Tags: flutter

hello im trying to make like this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4nDHeb8-38&t=32s

is there a way in flutter to make it??

im using

```
Container(
                    padding:EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    alignment:Alignment.center,
                    height:300,
                    child:
                        Container(
                            decoration: DottedDecoration(
                                shape: Shape.circle,
                                dash: <int>[1, 4],
                                color: Colors.blue,
                                strokeWidth: 2
                            ),
                            height:animation.value,
                            width: animation.value,
                        ),
                ),
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use AnimationController (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/tutorial)

Here is grow transition, from example

```
class GrowTransition extends StatelessWidget {
  GrowTransition({required this.child, required this.animation});

  final Widget child;
  final Animation<double> animation;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Center(
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: animation,
            builder: (context, child) => Container(
                  height: animation.value,
                  width: animation.value,
                  child: child,
                ),
            child: child),
      );
}
```